# JAXB-2 Maven Plugin and maxOccurs=5000 limitation

Tags: jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm using the JAXB-2 Maven Plugin to generate classes from an XSD. One element has a maxOccurs of 50000 so the secure processing feature causes an exception for violating the 5000 limit.

Changing the XSD is not an option so as a workaround I added the "-nv" parameter to turn off strict validation. So I got my classes but it doesn't feel like a real solution.

Is there a way to set the MAX_OCCUR_NODE_LIMIT?

Comment: Can you post the syntax to add the "-nv" parameter in the pom.xml?  Thanks.

Comment: You can do this with the jaxb2-maven-plugin as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610141/jaxb2-maven-plugin-throws-exception-when-maxoccurs-is-greater-than-5000