# jaxb2-maven-plugin throws Exception when maxOccurs is greater than 5000

Tags: maven, jaxb2-maven-plugin

When I run the jaxb2-maven-plugin on a legacy xsd it throws this Exception:

Current configuration of the parser doesn't allow a maxOccurs attribute value to be set greater than the value 5,000

Googling this error shows that this is a limit that was put on jaxp for security purposes.  It can be disabled in code like this

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,false);
```

but I need to do this in maven.  Also, xjc has a -nv switch to turn off this validation and that looks like the way to go.  I can't change the xsd.

What's the syntax for passing the -nv switch in the jaxb2-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My colleague Vic Ganora found the answer in the source code for the jaxb2-maven-plugin.  In the `<plugin>...<configuration>` element you need to add

```
 <laxSchemaValidation>true</laxSchemaValidation>
```